# How to write Spotify API in processing?

Tags: api, processing, spotify

For my project in college I have decided to make an interactive map where, when the user hovers over a country the title of the top song in that country is displayed. I wanted to get that title from Spotify charts.

I have read every single page of the Spotify API guide and I am still confused as to how should I write the query in processing. I have the authorisation code  and the OAuth token, but I'm not sure how should I include it in the actual sketch.

I really need all the help I can get, I am very new to this and I will appreciate every bit of advice.

Answer (score 1):

Use a *Spotify API Java Wrapper* such as [this one](https://github.com/thelinmichael/spotify-web-api-java) to handle API requests to Spotify.

Wrappers are external libraries that simplify API interfacing by providing functions that you can call from your code to make API requests. See [this](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/libraries) webpage for information about including external libraries in Processing sketches if you haven't done this before.

The most-played track per country isn't likely to change during operation of your program so requesting (it seems you've identified the correct API endpoint for this) the top track for each country just once is sufficient. This process could be done in *setup()*, for example, since it runs once only.

Then it's a matter of storing the data from these requests in some sort of data structure to allow your program to retrieve the most played track of the country that is being hovered over. A `HashMap` of *country name* to *top track* is appropriate, but there are many viable approaches.